# UV Islands stuck together

Tags: uv

I've been working on unwrapping a lego minifigure I've modeled and when reaching the hand I've got a problem with the inner part of the hand and the side of the hand's island becoming stuck together. There is a seam completely surrounding the inner hand, so it should be on its own, but the islands don't separate. I've been unwrapping and then hitting "follow active quads" on even, and it's worked so far. Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! I had to toggle "keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync" off and select one of the islands and move it, then when I turned it back on the islands were separated. Don't know why that worked, but I'm glad it did!

Answer (score 0):

Press L to select the separate islands

Comment: That's not having any effect...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/70814)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I don't see how this isn't an answer. This does *attempt* to provide an answer, regardless of the detail or accuracy of it.